# Tensorflow Error: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm facing a trouble with tensorFlow. Following codes is OK.

from **future** import division, print_function, absolute_import

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim
from tensorflow.contrib.layers.python.layers import initializers
from tensorflow.python.ops import init_ops

config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
sess = tf.Session(config=config)

# Visualize decoder setting
# Parameters
training_epochs = 100
batch_size = 50
display_step = 40

LEARNING_RATE = 0.001
# LEARNING_RATE_BASE = 0.01
# LEARNING_RATE_DECAY = 0.99

min_after_dequeue = 1000
TRAINING_SAMPLE_SIZE = 3365

IMAGE_SIZE1 = 40
IMAGE_SIZE2 = 80
IMAGE_CHANNEL = 1
DEEP_SIZE = 8

def inference(x, reuse=False):
    # Building the encoder
    with tf.variable_scope('inference') as scope:
        if reuse:
            scope.reuse_variables()
        with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d], padding='SAME',
            weights_initializer=initializers.xavier_initializer(),
            weights_regularizer=None,
            biases_initializer=init_ops.zeros_initializer(),
            biases_regularizer=None,
            normalizer_fn=slim.batch_norm,
            activation_fn=tf.nn.relu):
            net = slim.conv2d(x, DEEP_SIZE, [2, 2], stride=1, scope='conv1')
            net = slim.conv2d(net, DEEP_SIZE*2, [2, 2], stride=1, scope='conv2')
            net = slim.conv2d(net, DEEP_SIZE, [2, 2], stride=1, scope='conv3')
            # net = slim.conv2d(net, DEEP_SIZE*2, [2, 2], stride=1, scope='conv4')
            # net = slim.conv2d(net, DEEP_SIZE, [2, 2], stride=1, scope='conv5')
            net = slim.conv2d(net, IMAGE_CHANNEL, [2, 2], stride=1, activation_fn=None, scope='conv6')
    return net

# Construct model
def train():
    # tf Graph input (only pictures)
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, IMAGE_SIZE1, IMAGE_SIZE2, IMAGE_CHANNEL])
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, IMAGE_SIZE1, IMAGE_SIZE2, IMAGE_CHANNEL])

    y_pred = inference(x)
    y_true = y

    cost = tf.reduce_mean((y_pred - y_true) ** 2)
    # cost = - tf.reduce_mean(y_true * tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, 1e-10, 1.0)))
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE).minimize(cost)

    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
    # Launch the graph
    with tf.Session(config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement = True, log_device_placement = True)) as sess:
        sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()])
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

        total_batch = TRAINING_SAMPLE_SIZE // batch_size
        # Training cycle
        loss_init = 100000000
        for epoch in range(training_epochs):
            # Loop over all batches
            loss = 0
            for i in range(total_batch):
                batch_xs = sess.run(input_imgs)
                batch_ys = sess.run(label_imgs)
                batch_ys1 = (batch_ys<0.5)*0.
                batch_ys2 = (batch_ys>0.5)*1.
                batch_ys = batch_ys1 + batch_ys2
                # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
                _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y: batch_ys})
                # Display logs per epoch step
                if i % display_step == 0:
                    print(epoch+1,'\t', i+1, '\t', "{:.9f}".format(c))

                    # Compare original images with their reconstructions
                    a = 0
                    for j in range(1):
                        xs = sess.run(input_imgs)
                        ys = sess.run(label_imgs)
                        ys1 = (ys<0.5)*0.
                        ys2 = (ys>0.5)*1.
                        ys = ys1 + ys2
                        encode_decode = sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={x: xs, y:ys})
                        for i in range(5):
                            # plt.imshow(xs[i].reshape(IMAGE_SIZE1, IMAGE_SIZE2), cmap='Greys_r')
                            # plt.axis('off')  #不显示坐标轴
                            # fig = plt.gcf()  
                            # fig.set_size_inches(IMAGE_SIZE2/300, IMAGE_SIZE1/300)
                            # plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())  
                            # plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())  
                            # plt.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0, right = 1, left = 0, hspace = 0, wspace = 0)  
                            # plt.margins(0,0)  
                            # fig.savefig('autoencoder_AE/input/%d.jpg' % a, transparent=True, dpi=300, pad_inches = 0)

                            plt.imshow(ys[i].reshape(IMAGE_SIZE1, IMAGE_SIZE2), cmap='Greys_r')
                            plt.axis('off')  #不显示坐标轴
                            fig = plt.gcf()  
                            fig.set_size_inches(IMAGE_SIZE2/300, IMAGE_SIZE1/300)
                            plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())  
                            plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())  
                            plt.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0, right = 1, left = 0, hspace = 0, wspace = 0)  
                            plt.margins(0,0)  
                            fig.savefig('autoencoder_AE/label/%d.jpg' % a, transparent=True, dpi=300, pad_inches = 0)

                            plt.imshow(encode_decode[i].reshape(IMAGE_SIZE1, IMAGE_SIZE2), cmap='Greys_r')
                            plt.axis('off')  #不显示坐标轴
                            fig = plt.gcf()  
                            fig.set_size_inches(IMAGE_SIZE2/300, IMAGE_SIZE1/300)
                            plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())  
                            plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())  
                            plt.subplots_adjust(top = 1, bottom = 0, right = 1, left = 0, hspace = 0, wspace = 0)  
                            plt.margins(0,0)  
                            fig.savefig('autoencoder_AE/predict/%d.jpg' % a, transparent=True, dpi=300, pad_inches = 0)

                            a = a + 1
            if loss < loss_init:
                saver.save(sess,'AE_simp_model/autoencoder.ckpt')
                loss_init = loss
        print("Optimization Finished!")
train()
```

However, when the inference() has been changed to:

```
def inference(x, reuse=False):
    # Building the encoder
    with tf.variable_scope('inference') as scope:
        if reuse:
            scope.reuse_variables()
        with slim.arg_scope([slim.conv2d], padding='SAME',
            weights_initializer=initializers.xavier_initializer(),
            weights_regularizer=None,
            biases_initializer=init_ops.zeros_initializer(),
            biases_regularizer=None,
            normalizer_fn=slim.batch_norm,
            activation_fn=tf.nn.relu):
            net = slim.conv2d(x, DEEP_SIZE, [2, 2], stride=1, scope='conv1')
            net = slim.conv2d(net, DEEP_SIZE*2, [2, 2], stride=1, scope='conv2')
            net = slim.conv2d(net, DEEP_SIZE, [2, 2], stride=1, scope='conv3')
            # net = slim.conv2d(net, DEEP_SIZE*2, [2, 2], stride=1, scope='conv4')
            # net = slim.conv2d(net, DEEP_SIZE, [2, 2], stride=1, scope='conv5')
            net = slim.conv2d(net, IMAGE_CHANNEL, [2, 2], stride=1, activation_fn=None, scope='conv6')
            net = tf.reshape(net, [-1, 1])
            a = tf.ones_like(net) * 0.5
            net = tf.concat([net, a], 1)
            net = tf.arg_max(net, 1)
            net = tf.cast(net, tf.float32)
            net = tf.reshape(net, [batch_size, IMAGE_SIZE1, IMAGE_SIZE2, IMAGE_CHANNEL])
    return net
```

The mistake "No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables" appeared.

Comment: `tf.arg_max` is not differentiable!

Answer (score 0):

As the error already tells you, there is an operation (op) for wich tensorflow cannot compute a gradient. In your case, the op `tf.arg_max` is the problem. This function is not differentiable (i.e. no derivative exists and hence no gradient can be computed). Tensorflow can therfore not create gradients for any variable in the graph and throws this error.

The solution is to design a network that only uses differentiable functions and to get rid of the `tf.arg_max`. As you did not explain what your intentions with your network design are, it is hard to tell how to re-design your `inference` function in this case. I can only guess that you would rather want something like `softmax` to get prediction probabilities for each of your classes. This can then be used in a loss function for training.

Even if your desired target image has only the values 0 and 1, it is not reasonable to force the network to only output zeros and ones. Instead, you want a continuous output that can be interpreted as (unscaled) probabilities. You need continuous values in order to calculate well defined derivatives so that your loss function can be optimised via gradient decent.

Of course, after the training phase you can you `argmax` to set all pixels with predicted value <0.5 to zero and the others to 1. This, however, should not be done during training.

Comment: The purpose of this NN is to obtain a gray level image, and if a pixel < 0.5, the pixel will be changed to 0, otherwise, the pixel will be 1. So would you have some ideas to solve it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you want to train a NN for a task that has straight forward algorithmic implementation? Converting an image to gray scale is not a task that has to be learned.

Comment: The objective images only have two kinds of pixels: 0 and 1. Therefore, in my opinion, if the output pixels of the NN are changed to 0 and 1, the accuracy of NN might be improved.

Comment: @liyu I extended my answer.